# Cannot navigate from one view controller to another with button

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

It gives:

> signal SIGABRT

Another error in log says:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
@IBAction func loginok(sender: AnyObject) {
    if loginTextField?.text != "monal" && passwordTextField?.text  != "gosai"
    {
        warningLable?.text = "Invalid Credentials"

        loginTextField?.text = ""
        passwordTextField?.text=""
    }
    else
    {
        let View2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as! ViewController2
         self.navigationController!.pushViewController(View2, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PerformSegueWithIdentifier` won't work unless you've set up a segue in the storyboard. If you have, then in your `else` statement as Francisco stated you should call that function. If you have not set up the segue on the Storyboard then you will have to do so to use this method.

Also, as a matter of convention, your `@IBAction` method header should read `func loginok(sender: UIButton) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a identifier to the segue and then call it with

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: can you try it with a _safe let_  like this `if let View2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as? ViewController2 {
         self.navigationController!.pushViewController(View2, animated: true) }` maybe the error is on the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and not in `pushViewController`, this is will not resolve your problem but maybe gives you a better approach

Comment: That is what I was going to suggest too. When I faced this issue it was due to errors in typing so the issue may be the same here.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard click on the segue and in Utilities->Attributes inspector->Identifier  type a name , I used "mySegue" 
Below the Identifier, for Segue , make it Modal.

create a button and ctrl drag to the m file:
This is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)nAction:(UIButton *)sender {
        self.mytext =  self.mytextfield.text;
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:sender];
    }



    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"])
        {
        NSLog(@" my segues is called mysegue");
        myViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController] ;
        controller.textforlabel = self.mytext;
        }
```

Don't forget to include the h file where you define the destination viewcontroller for the segue :)